# use Homebrew to create redistributable dynamic libraries

Tags: homebrew

I want to build redistributable libraries (for example: FFmpeg and all its dependencies) with Homebrew. Basically, I guess all I need is to pass `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` or `--with-macos-sdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk` or so but I'm not sure. A related question about how to pass custom CFLAGS is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/670291/homebrew-with-custom-cflags). Is this enough? Are other people doing this? How?